# Play MP4 from byte[] in C# console or windows form

Tags: c#, arrays, mp4

I want to play an MP4 video from byteArray in C#.(I must play it from byteArray)

```
byte[] f = File.ReadAllBytes("./sample.mp4");

Play(f);
```

I want to play the `f` and I can't find any `Play` library or function.

*note: I can't play file from file directly and **must play the byte[]**.*

Is there any way to do it by **C# .net core console app** or **C# .net windows form**?

Comment: Why must it be a byte array if you dont know which library to use? You should focus on finding a appropiate playback library first.

Comment: This is a client app and I can't change the server side code and it send me a byteArray and I must play it :(

Comment: Ah, okay... that helps. Still you should focus on finding an appropiate playback library. Usually playback libraries use a `Stream` object to perform playback - do not let this hold you back. byte[] is easily converted to Stream.

Comment: You could save the data to a temp file and then play it. Or see if you could find a library which accepts a stream instead of a file to play. Then you could just stream the array into it

Comment: @Stefan , do you know some library for play a Stream of mp4 video?

Comment: I think WPF has got better support for this. You might try to search the web for C# WPF Mp4